# Value getting reset between ajax calls in Controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my controller, the method that returns the View also initializes a few values for some class-level properties:

```
private string igc = String.Empty;
private string igcCode = String.Empty;
private bool isSuggested = false;

public ActionResult Codes(Codes objCodes)
{
    try
    {
        FillDropDowns(objCodes);
        igc = String.Empty;
        if (objICDCodes.FromWhere.IndexOf("MedicalInfo-Suggested") >= 0)
        {
            igc = objCodes.FromWhere.Remove(0, "MedicalInfo-Suggested-".Length);
            igcCode = igc.Substring(0, igc.IndexOf("-")).Trim();
            objCodes.ICGCode = igcCode;
            isSuggested = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //logging error
        ElmahLogUtility.ErrorException(ex);
    }

    return View(base.GetViewPath("Codes"), objCodes);
}
```

Additionally, there is this method which gets called to bind data to a grid on the page:

```
public JsonResult GetSelectedCodesInfo(List<SearchField> searchFields, GridDataSourceRequest request)
{
    //creating the instance of DataSourceResult.
    DataSourceResult dataSourceResult = null;
    try
    {
        // Creating the instance of CommonBLL to load the values.
        CommonBLL objCommonBLL = new CommonBLL();

        if (isSuggested)
        {
            searchFields.Add(new SearchField() { ElementName = "aIGCode", Value = igcCode });
            searchFields.Add(new SearchField() { ElementName = "aFor", Value = "EtiologicDiagnosis" });
        }

        // Getting the Codes information and storing in the DataSource Result.
        dataSourceResult = objCommonBLL.GetSelectedCodesInfo(searchFields, request);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Logging the Exception
        ElmahLogUtility.ErrorException(ex);
    }

    // Returning the Result.
    return Json(dataSourceResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

`isSuggested` gets set to `true` when the View is created, but when the data is bound to the grid `isSuggested` is set to `false` for some reason.

My grid is defined in a Razor view like so:

```
@Html.Grid("CodesSelectionGrid").ReadSource("Controller", "GetSelectedCodesInfo").OnGridDataBound("AssignCodeValues").Lazyload(true).EnableGrouping(false).EnableSorting(true).PageSize(10).Height("390px").Width("610px").EnablePaging(true).EnableFiltering(false).EnableMultiSelect(true).SelectionMode(SelectionMode.Single, "GetSelectedCodeDetails").RowSelection(GridRowSelection.None).ShowToolBar(true).SelectionCSSClass("icd-editable-cell").PageButtonCount(3)
```

That `.ReadSource("Controller", "GetSelectedCodesInfo")` bit is what refers to the Controller and the method on the controller to call. So, it's calling the second snippet of code above.

I must be accessing two separate instances of my `Controller` class, but I do not know how to solve this problem. How can I do this? How could I have my grid pass a reference of the `Codes` object? Then I could just get the values from there for the grid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. `isSuggested` is a class level variable. Every time you make an Http request, a new instance of your controller will be created. That means the variable will be initialized to false. Remember, **Http is Stateless** :)

If you want to persist a variable value between multiple http calls, you need to persist it. You have different options like

1. Persist to a database table and read from that in the second call
2. Write to a file in disk and read from that in the second call
3. Save to user session and read from that in the second call

Comment: Thanks; I suspected this was by design. I just didn't know how to deal with it. I'll probably just throw it into a session variable as you suggested. I'll accept your answer if that works.

Comment: Well, your solution solved my problem... but has problems of its own unfortunately. Thanks though!

Comment: 4. Pass it back and forth via hidden fields with an HTTP Post, similar to how Viewstate worked in asp.net.